# What is the primary principle of controlling Jinchuuriki?

Tags: naruto

What is the primary principle of controlling Jinchuuriki? I can think of two possibilities:

1. Control on hatred/negative thoughts;
2. Will and wish of tailed beast.

Killer Bee could easily get in a good relationship with Hachibi. We can recall the Falls of Truth incident of Bee, where he could easily pass it in a second, because he didn't have any hatred about anyone around him in his heart. So is it because he had suppressed negative thoughts, hence he got his tailed beast under control? Or is it because Hachibi himself is a really good guy, who is broadminded enough to lend his chakra to Bee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bijuu control can be achieved in 2 ways.

1. My (Madara Uchiha's) way, by force.
2. By earning the respect of the Tailed Beast in question.

In the past, when Madara battled Hashirama at the Valley of the End, he summoned and controlled the Nine Tails with the power of genjutsu, using the Sharingan.

> Naruto and Killerbee however, earned their respective Tailed Beast trust. The Tailed Beasts are ancient beings, very bitter about constantly being sealed and used by humans. They developed a deep resentment to humans. Naruto and Killerbee, by not succumbing with those powerful negative emotions, and showing their desire to work with, not against their Tailed Beast, have earned their respect, and achieved a whole new level of power.

The second method is by far stronger than the first.

Comment: one question! By force/ by earning respect.. which one does 'Tug Of War' belong to??

Comment: The force one. By submitting the bijuu to your will, you take his chakra. By befriending him, he'll give you chakra willingly.

Comment: yah .. and don't have to spend our chakra to control him isn't it? :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. By force, the bijuu drains your chakra. Willingly, he doesn't.